# Can we use multiple constants with different enums tags in C

Tags: c, enums

I have following code:

```
enum tag1 {
 n1, n2, n3
};

enum tag2 {
 n4, n5, n1
};
```

Now, I got an error, `n1` are used two times

So my question is what is the use of `enum tags` when enum constants doesn't have a scope.

Comment: If you want C++, you know where to look for it.  In C, enumeration constant names must be unique across all enumerations. That is simply the way C is defined.  There isn't a mechanism built into C to provide scoping. The closest approach is with structures and unions and member names.  But the analogy isn't very good.

Comment: Normal practice is to prefix your enum constants with something unique, for example if tag1 represents colors then the enum constants would be named something like `C_WHITE`, `C_RED`, `C_CYAN`, etc. Also because these constants are functionally equivalent to a bunch of `#define`s I personally like the all caps naming convention for these constants

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use it like this. Enums in "C" are not strongly typed.

Using enums increase the level of abstraction and lets the programmer think about what the values mean rather than worry about how they are stored and accessed. This reduces the occurrence of bugs.

Enums have these benefits:

- They restrict the values that the enum variable can take
- They force you to think about all the possible values that the enum can take.
- They are a constant rather than a number, increasing readability of the source code

Comment: `enum` constants in C *are* strongly typed, they are all `int` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum` tags to declare variables of type of the corresponding `enum` without using a `typedef`:

```
enum tag1 varName = n5;
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to have several `enum`s sharing a member in the same translation unit. Obviously, you can define your two `enum`s in different headers, and make full use of them, as long as the two headers are not included in the same `C` file.